# React Native run-android failed due to "couldn't delete stale output file" error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, npx

I'm new to React Native and want to run my first template app in an AVD (Android Virtual Device) VM. I've started the VM and it's running. I'm running "npx react-native start" in a separate command window that has admin rights. I'm running the command "npx react-native run-android" in Visual Studio Code, but then it fails with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':expo-linear-gradient:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
Couldn't delete stale output file
```

I've looked endlessly online but can't seem to find anything related to this issue. I've deleted my "build" file in my android folder, rebooted my pc, etc. nothing seemd to work.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Yeah, i have the same error. have you solve it?>

Comment: Strangely, yesterday I could just run it! Maybe restarting my PC helped and doing nothing else before starting the emulators, metro bundler, code etc... Also running everything in Administrator mode wouldn't hurt. Sadly I didn't do anything particular to fix this, it just worked... Sorry I cant be of more help!

Comment: ahhaha, i also fixed it by, resubmiting `yarn install`

Comment: Yes maybe deleting node_modules or something and reinstalling them all could fix it too

Comment: yes, codes in recent years getting weirder